# Hex has unknown character / in the output

Tags: encryption, openssl, hex, xxd

I need to create a `Rc2Key` variable and then convert this to hexadecimal.  I have done this with two commands.  The `Rc2Key` variable has to be 16 characters long, so in my test module I used "DummyRC2Key1" as the `Rc2Key`.

```
Rc2Key="DummyRC2Key1"

HexRc2Key=$(printf "${Rc2Key}" | xxd -p)
```

With that done I need to pad the CTF keys with eight `0`s.  I did this with the following commands and output this padded list to CTFpadlist.csv

```
zeros=00000000

while read CTFlist; do echo $CTFlist$zeros; done < CTFlist.csv > CTFpadlist.csv
```

With the padded CTF's and the `HexRc2Key`, I need to encrypt the CTFpadlist.csv

```
while read CTFpadlist; do echo -n "$CTFpadlist" | xxd -r -p | openssl enc -rc2-cbc -nopad -K "${HexRc2Key}" -iv 0000000000000000 | xxd -plain | tr d '/n'; done < CTFpadlist.csv > EncCTFlist.csv
```

Here is the problem—my hex comes out with "/" like so:

```
24a8/be115/59a9/c62bbfe6249fbc/44af127fcf97a0a43
```

This is not an acceptable hex.  What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than

```
tr d '/n';
```

you probably meant

```
tr -d '\n';
```

Comment: Thank you sirby you pointing out the improper placement i located the problem.  just by deleting the '/n' fixed the problem.  Thank you

Comment: how do i accept it? i clicked the up arrow

Comment: nevermind...duhh