# printf in my output now

Tags: shell-script

The encryption on [this problem](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/279000/hex-has-unknown-character-in-the-output) just got more interesting. I started with this script:

```
while read CTFlist; do 

#next we need to create ctfs padded with zeros as a variable
ctfPadded=(printf ${ctflist}00000000)

#then call rc2 key as variable
rc2Key="TemporaryRC2Key1"

#next create a hex version of the rc2 key
hexRc2Key=$(printf "${rc2Key}"|xxd -p)

#next to create the encrypted ctf file using the hex rc2 key
ctfEnc= $(printf "${ctfPadded}" |xxd -r -p |openssl enc -rc2-cbc -nopad -K "${hexRc2Key}" -iv 0000000000000000 |xxd -plain|tr -d '\n')

#Now we call all our variables and output to a single file.
echo ${ctfPadded},${ctfEnc^^} >> output.csv

#calling end of file with the input file of ctflist.csv
done <CTFlist.csv

#have to change the output file to dos version or it wont open on a windows comp
unix2dos output.csv
```

The output.csv file has printf on every line down the list. Why? what is incorrect?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [running command in Mobax Terminal are there plugins that are needed](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/279600/running-command-in-mobax-terminal-are-there-plugins-that-are-needed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ommited a dollar sign in command substitution here:

```
ctfPadded=(printf ${ctflist}00000000)
```

This line should read:

```
ctfPadded=$(printf ${ctflist}00000000)
```

Comment: Thank you sometimes the smallest thing can be overlooked when moving too fast.  I really appreciate your response, EXCELLENT Answer!!

Comment: in the following commands the printf has been fixed but my output is the padded csv file and the encrypted output is showing    "bash: 009bd5584e2e89aafbd42cb3316b39695c74d2e5371ae7de: command not found" in the terminal

Comment: @DJLee I don't see how your script could result in such an error. Try putting `echo`s in between lines to see which one generates it.

Comment: There's no `opkPadded` in your original question. Anyway, I don't see how this can fail. Maybe factor it out into a number of variables and use `echo`s to debug further?

Comment: the error is following my apologies fast typing  `ctfEnc= $(printf "${ctfPadded}" |xxd -r -p |openssl enc -rc2-cbc -nopad -K "${hexRc2Key}" -iv 0000000000000000 |xxd -plain|tr -d '\n')`

Comment: ok i will try that, i felt the same way i keep running it and the padded ctf is showing in the output.csv and the ctfenc is in the terminal.  Thanks for your assistance i think i may have found it,  i will post

Comment: Tried it with `cftlist=123`, still can't make it fail the way it does for you. Are you sure you didn't make any additional changes to the code? Maybe it's time to open another question (this time with example input and output)?

Comment: ok i will thanks for your assistance.  Very helpful